# How do I create a function that passes all its arguments to another function

Tags: function, lua, minecraft, computercraft

I am trying to setup some functions in a program I am toying with that monitors my Extreme Reactors Turbine (Formally Big Reactors).  Most of the functions I am trying to do are... quite simple but saves me from having to line out certain blocks of code a hundred times.

Essentially what I would like to be able to do is stop using `mon.setCursorPos(x, y)` where `x` and `y` are the exact axis (e.g. `mon.setCursorPos(1,9)`) and replace it with something simpler like `cursor(1,9)`.  The problem is I am not really sure how to setup the function...

```
function cursor()
  mon.setCursorPos()
end
```

The above wouldn't properly work, an error would occur because of the missing string value within `()` of the `setCursorPos` api call.  I am still fairly new to LUA and honestly, not a great coder but trying to learn to not be so messy and draw things out where I don't have to.  Any help/tips are appreciated, happy coding to all!

Answer (score 3):

To pass arguments down you first need to define them in your own "wrapper" function *(here x and y)*:

```
function cursor(x, y)
    mon.setCursorPos(x, y)
end
```

If you don't know how many arguments there are you can use varargs syntax, `...`, to capture the arguments to `cursor` and pass them to `mon.setCursorPos`:

```
function cursor(...)
    mon.setCursorPos(...)
end
```

But a simpler way is to just do

```
cursor = mon.setCursorPos
```

so that `cursor` simply refers to the same function as `mon.setCursorPos`.